# How to create a Perl hash with values as list of lists

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a hash from the raw data read from a file.
The values for each hash element will be a list of lists. These inner lists are parsed from the file and need to be kept as a key => ((list 1), (list 2), ......, (list n)) in hash for further processing.

Final data that is expected in the hash will be something like:

```
%hash = {
    'key 1' => ((A, B, C), (1, 2, 3), (Q, R, F)),
    'key 2' => ((X, Y, Z), (P, Q, R)),
    'key 3' => ((1.0, M, N), (R, S, T), (4, 7, 9)),
      ......,
    'key n' => ((5, M, 8), (J, K, L), (1, 3, 4))
}
```

I wanted to keep them as a hash for easier lookup and to catch the duplicate keys

```
my %hash;
my @array = ();
my @inner_array = ();

open (my $FH, '<', $input_file) or die "Could not open : $!\n";

while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    chomp $line;

    ## Lines making up $key and @inner_array
    ## e.g. $key = 'key 1' and
    ## @inner_array = (A, B, C)
    ## @inner_array = (1, 2, 3)

    if (exists $hash{$key}) {         # We have seen this key before    
        @array = $hash{$key};         # Get the existing array 
        push(@array, @inner_array);   # Append new inner list 
        $hash{$key} = @array;         # Replace the original list

    } else {                  # Seeing the key for the first time
        @array = ();                  # Create empty list
        push (@array, @inner_list);   # Append new inner list 
        $hash{$key} = @array;         # Replace the original list
    }
}

close $FH;

print dumper %hash;
```

when executed on a sample file of 10 lines, I am getting the output like below:

```
$VAR1 = {
       'key 1' => 2,
       'key 2' => 2,
       'key 3' => 2
    };
```

Rather than seeing an array of arrays, I am getting scalar value 2 as the value of each hash element. Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I cannot see where `@inner_array` gets set except the initial empty array. And what's `@inner_list`? Anyway you'd have to work with array refs rather than arrays. Please [edit] your post and add a sample for the file your program should consume.

Comment: Thank you @stickybit . The problem was solved when I used array ref

Answer (score 2):

`((A, B, C), (1, 2, 3), (Q, R, F))` is equivalent to `(A, B, C, 1, 2, 3, Q, R, F)`, lists are flattened in Perl. Hash values must be scalars, you need to use an array reference:

```
my %hash = ( key => [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 'Q', 'R', 'F' ] ] ...
```

Note the square brackets for array references.

Also note the round parenthesis at the beginning: using `{` creates a hash reference, which you probably don't want to assign to a hash. It would've created a hash of a single key like `HASH(0x5653cc6cc1e0)` with undefined value.
Using [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) should tell you so:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -wE 'my %h = {x=>1}; say Dumper \%h'
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1.
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x557d282e41e0)' => undef
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not providing answer for your question instead I am giving the reason for your output. This is because of "implicit scalar conversion" it stores the array length. for example,

```
my @ar = qw(1 2 3 4);
my $x = @ar;
# output 4 (total length of array)
```

Use the reference to holds the data in your hash, as follow

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

my @array = (1,2,3,1);

@{$hash{"key"}} = @array;


print Dumper \%hash;
```

Then you have to understand the array flatten in Perl, Let's consider

```
@ar = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(3,4,5));
print $ar[0];
# output is 1 not (1,2,3) this is because array flatten
```

If you want to access the data as array format again you have to store it as reference

```
my @ar = ( [1,3,4] , [5,4,2] );

print @{$ar[0]};
#1,3,4
```

Comment: Thank you @mkHun. I could solve it by using array ref rather than arrays